# custom error page for virto commerce storefront

Tags: virtocommerce

in customErrors for virto commerce storefront, exist defaultRedirect="~/ServerMaintenance.aspx".
 so in statusCode="500" show ServerMaintenance.
but in statusCode="500" i need to show C500.aspx
I change webconfig to

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/ServerMaintenance.aspx">
<error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Status/C500.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

But in statusCode="500" do not show C500.aspx, and show And shows  page with following error :

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.
```

Where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message on your response says there is an error on your custom error page, that's why you can't see it. Try to switch off custom errors

```
<system.web>
   <customErrors mode="Off"...
```

and make a request to C500.aspx directly - you should see what's wrong with it.

Comment: oh yes, there is an error on my custom error page,I got it right and it worked. thanks